# Internet download manager keeps on downloading a file even after I logout from my captive portal

Tags: wireless-networking, bittorrent, captive-portal, wifi-transfer, bypass

I entered my phone number and otp on a public wifi and started downloading a file using idm. After some time I logged out and the download was still going on with full speed how is this possible.
Can someone explain please.

Comment: Logging out did not end the session so that downloading continued. If you did not want the download, you should end it first before logging out.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer.

Comment: I will post this as an answer as you seem to be happy with it

Answer (score 1):

Logging out did not end the session so that downloading continued. If you did not want the download, you should end it first before logging out. That is what I always do.

Note:  You can log out of Windows (likely other operating systems as well) and Updates happen even when logged out.